# Changing the field of a column for view purposes only. Codeigniter and PostgreSQL

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm using codeigniter and postgreSQL.

I have a table

```
column1    column2    column3    total
   0          0          0        0
   5          0          3        8
   0         500        256      756
```

What I want to view is that

```
column1    column2    column3    total
   -          -          -        -
   5          -          3        8
   -         500        256      756
```

Which means is that if the data is 0 I'll change it to '-' and ofcourse w/o changing the real value in the database. It's just for view purposes only. Can it be done?

EDIT----------------------------
Here's the code

```
  foreach ($value as = $v){ ?>
   <tr>
      <td><?php echo $v->column1?></td>
      <td><?php echo $v->column2?></td>
      <td><?php echo $v->column3?></td>
      <td><?php echo $v->column1+$v->column2+$v->column3?></td>
   </tr>
```

EDIT2-----------------------------

What about this code:

```
$column1=0;
echo $column1;
```

The display should be "-" instead of 0.

I've already tried

($column1 == 0? "-":$column1)

Still no changes but no error.

Comment: Why not. Fetch the data from your database then assign it to a variable. On that variable is where you're going to manipulate the 0 to - before rendering it to the view. Show your existing code.

Comment: @dqlopez Can you give me a sample code?

Comment: PostgreSQL knows conditional expressions like most other SQL implementations … so you could do that in your query already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php echo ($v->column1 == 0 ? "-" : $v->column1); ?>
<?php echo ($v->column2 == 0 ? "-" : $v->column2); ?>
....
```

Comment: tnx. sorry for the very late reply.

Comment: uhmm. when I tried <?php echo ($column1 == 0 ? "-" : $column1); ?> w/o the $v. it doesn't work (it's not an error but there's no change). How can I make it work?

Comment: @kino, that comment makes no sense – if your values are properties of an object `$v`, then why do you expect them to be accessible in a totally different way out of the blue?

Comment: @CBroe What if it is not a part of the object $v. Should I use IF statement here?

Comment: The ternary operator `?` works with every value, no matter “where” it comes from. // We can’t tell you what you are doing wrong, as long as you don’t describe _what_ exactly you’re doing. (But please don’t post code examples in comments now, but instead edit your question by appending what exactly you are having problems with now.)

Comment: @CBroe can u pls. see my EDIT 2 above and give me sample code so that I can understand it. EDIT 2 is not related to EDIT.

Comment: And what exactly is your problem with applying the same logic that Fabiano has shown you in this answer to that case …?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48791/discussion-between-kino-and-cbroe)

Comment: @CBroe I'm really really sorry for confusing
Im still learning
I already tried ($column1 == 0? "-":$column1) for EDIT 2 but still not working. No error but no changes.

Comment: Works perfectly fine, as you can see here: http://3v4l.org/MYFaf – How _you_ are able to f*ck something this simple up is however still unclear, since you are still only giving fragmented information and no simple, clean, small, copy&paste-ready example of what you are actually doing – please _work_ on that for the future, otherwise talking about such problems with you is quite a drag.